# infinitest (eclipse) no related tests found for last change since moving tests

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, infinitest

I have moved our unit tests from a separate project to the actual project they are being tested in from a separate test project. We now have the following folder structure:

```
/src/main/java...
/test/main/java...
```

I have added the test folder to the build path of the project and this, along with src gets built to the /bin folder.

When I make a change to a class, infinitest says "No related tests found for last change". When the tests were in a separate project, infinitest was able to run them as expected. I have no filters file to filter tests in this project.

Any ideas?

Comment: The tests run if I move them to:
    /src/test/java....
I can only assume that they are required to be in the /src/ folder.

Comment: Since moving them to `/src/test` allowed them to work, I would guess all you needed to do was mark `/test` as a source folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that was driving me nuts. Turns out that Infinitest doesn't like spaces in the path to the source files. I had a space in my workspace directory name. Removing the space solved the problem.